# How to add license key functionality for Acumatica custom ISV product

Tags: acumatica

We have a custom solution made up of several screens that are packaged as a customization package.  We'd like to be able to lock that down so that users need to purchase a license key to use these screens.   I don't want to re-invent the wheel, so I'm wondering if there are standard examples (if this has been done before) on how to integrate this with Acumatica's license system.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to integrate with the Acumatica licensing system. We implemented our own licensing and required the license when the Acumatica license has been applied. This is indicated by `PXLicenseHelper.License.Licensed`

I should point out I did spend a good amount of time on this very question before we implemented licensing for our product.